# Example on how to do asynchronous http get request using cpp-netlib

Tags: c++, asynchronous, compiler-errors, http-request, cpp-netlib

I'm trying to do asynchronous http requests using [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.github.com/latest/index.html). I couldn't find any examples of this in the documentation, as a result can't even get it to compile. My current attempt is below (with compilation errors in the comments). Any hints how to make it work? Thank you in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/network/protocol/http/client.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::network;
using namespace boost::network::http;

typedef function<void(boost::iterator_range<char const *> const &, boost::system::error_code const &)> body_callback_function_type; // ERROR: Expected initializer before '<' token

body_callback_function_type callback() // ERROR: 'body_callback_function_type' does not name a type
{
    cout << "This is my callback" << endl;
}

int main() {
    http::client client;
    http::client::request request("http://www.google.com/");
    http::client::response response = client.get(request, http::_body_handler=callback()); // ERROR: 'callback' was not declared in this scope
    cout << body(response) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not used cpp-netlib, but it looks like there's some obvious issues with your code:

First error is a missing `boost::` on the function typedef.

```
typedef function<void(boost::iterator_range<char const *> const &, boost::system::error_code const &)> body_callback_function_type; // ERROR: Expected initializer before '<' token
```

Should be

```
typedef boost::function<void(boost::iterator_range<char const *> const &, boost::system::error_code const &)> body_callback_function_type;
```

Second error is:

```
body_callback_function_type callback() 
{
    cout << "This is my callback" << endl;
}
```

Should be the right kind of function:

```
void callback( boost::iterator_range<char const *> const &, boost::system::error_code const &)
{
    cout << "This is my callback" << endl;
}
```

Third error is that you should pass the callback, not call it:

```
http::client::response response = client.get(request, http::_body_handler=callback());
```

Should be

```
http::client::response response = client.get(request, callback);
```

Hopefully thats all (or enough to get you started).